# How to switch axes (dimensions) in Julia for n-dimensional array

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, julia

I have an array that I would like to switch the axes order of. It is similar to a transpose except I would like to perform it on arrays with dimensions greater than 2. In Python I would use np.transpose and in Matlab, permute, but I can't seem to find this in Julia. For instance,

```
a = ones(2, 3, 4)
size(a)
(2,3,4)
```

From this I would like to get an array of shape (3, 4, 2) by rearranging the axes (dimensions) to (2, 3, 1). I am looking for a function called new_func.

```
b = new_func(a, (2, 3, 1))
size(b)
(3,4,2)
```

Comment: Is http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.permutedims what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, that is it. Missed it in the docs.

Comment: No worries. I guess I should post an answer, but s.o. generally doesn't like single-link answers.

Answer (score 10):

According to Stefan Karpinski, the answer is `Base.permutedims` ([docs](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/arrays/#Base.permutedims)).

Example:

```
a = ones(2, 3, 4)
size(a) # => (2,3,4)

b = permutedims(a, [2, 3, 1])
size(b) # => (3,4,2)
```